# Getting a Parse Error with a Wordpress feed

Tags: parsing, xmldocument, delphi-10.3-rio

I am having a problem parsing a WordPress Feed using the XMLDocument component. When reading the feed, I get a parsing error on line 52. I see the single quote in the word won't is being changed to Wasnx92t. But that shouldn't cause a problem since it is being converted.

The XML feed can be found here: https://minttoreport.com/feed/

```
procedure TMainForm.RefreshNews(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;
  StartItemNode : IXMLNode;
  ANode : IXMLNode;
  STitle, sDesc, sLink : WideString;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.text := OnlineRegForm.GetUrlContent('https://minttoreport.com/feed/');
  sl.SaveToFile(ReportFolder+'news.xml');
  XMLDocument1.FileName := ReportFolder+'news.xml';
  XMLDocument1.Active := true;
  StartItemNode := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('item') ;
  ANode := StartItemNode;
  STitle := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
  sLink := ANode.ChildNodes['link'].Text;
  sDesc := ANode.ChildNodes['description'].Text;
  WebBrowser2.LoadFromStrings('<h4><a href="'+sLink+'" '+ sTitle+'"</a></h4>"','');
  Showmessage('<h4><a href="'+sLink+'" '+ sTitle+'"</a></h4>"');
```

This is a WordPress, latest release, from https://minttoreport.com/feed

I get the error on when I activate the XMLDocument component.

Comment: I used https://www.xmlvalidation.com against the file and it said there were no errors. Now how to get XMLDocument component to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a Delphi 10.3 bug, but I fixed the problem just by setting the
XML property to the contents of the file rather than using the FileName property.
Same results in the IDE. So here is the changed code:

```
procedure TMainForm.RefreshNews(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;
  StartItemNode : IXMLNode;
  ANode : IXMLNode;
  STitle, sDesc, sLink : WideString;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.text := OnlineRegForm.GetUrlContent('https://minttoreport.com/feed/');
  //sl.SaveToFile(ReportFolder+'news.xml');
  //XMLDocument1.FileName := ReportFolder+'news.xml';
  XMLDocument1.XML.Text := sl.Text;
  XMLDocument1.Active := true;
  StartItemNode := XMLDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.First.ChildNodes.FindNode('item') ;
  ANode := StartItemNode;
//  repeat
    STitle := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
    sLink := ANode.ChildNodes['link'].Text;
    sDesc := ANode.ChildNodes['description'].Text;
    WebBrowser2.LoadFromStrings('<h4><a href="'+sLink+'" '+ sTitle+'"</a></h4>"','');
    Showmessage('<h4><a href="'+sLink+'" '+ sTitle+'"</a></h4>"');
```